Is Frechet Inception Distance (FID) suitable for evaluating GAN performance on tabular datasets like Iris
I am new to generative AI and working on evaluating the performance of GAN models in a federated learning setup with a tabular dataset (e.g., the Iris dataset). I am exploring different metrics to evaluate the generator's performance.
I came across Frechet Inception Distance (FID), which is widely used in image-based GANs to measure the quality and diversity of generated samples. However, my dataset is tabular, not image-based, and I am not sure if FID is applicable in this context.
Is FID suitable for evaluating GANs trained on tabular datasets like Iris?
Note: I am not looking for visualization-based comparisons (e.g., PCA, t-SNE). My goal is to use a single, quantitative metric for generator performance.
